# What is the custom Facebook share code to have separate urls indexed

Tags: php, facebook

Am using facebook share code, but dont know how to customize the url part so that user who is on that url page should be shared instead of default url.

My current code is like

```
 <a onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/? 
 u=mycarhelpline.com', 'newWindow', 'width=600, height=400'); return false;" 
 href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u=mycarhelpline.com" target="_blank" 
 rel="nofollow">
```

I need to customize the line

```
?u=mycarhelpline.com
```

with a php code that so that url which is been accessed by the user should come in share window instead of default home page.

(Know that Share option is deprecated, but sharing works for me - look for help to customize the code of sharing url

Thanks

**Edited**

Hi have put in revised code, i know am doing some error - pl help n suggest for rectification

```
   <?php
   $server_name = 'mycarhelpline.com';
   $current_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $sharerpath = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$server_name  .'/'.$current_path;
    ?>

   <a onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$sharerpath', 'newWindow', 'width=600, height=400'); return false;" 
   href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$sharerpath''" target="_blank" 
   rel="nofollow"><img src="/templates/mycar_home/images/facebook.png" alt="Share on Facebook" /></a>
```

Now when i put ?> after  tag, its showing server error and is not displaying page and when put before http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$sharerpath

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the share plugin to simply share the current page the user is on. For this you will have to customize the plugin.  Every time you place the share code on your page, you'll have to specify what page the user is on.

You can use parameters within the `$_SERVER` variable for this. You already know the server name, then you have the `REQUEST_URI` which is the URI which was given in order to access this page. So if you combine them you should reach a final URL for each page.

```
$server_name = 'mycarhelpline.com';
$current_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$sharerPath = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$server_name .'/'.$current_path;
```

References -

- [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Sure, thanx for quick reply. What is request URI? what do i need to mention in request URI, do i need to speak to the host provider for it.. thnx

Comment: Sure, but What is request URI? what do i need to mention in request URI, do i need to speak to the host provider for it

Comment: @gag - not at all.  Take a look at `$_SERVER` variable. I've added a link to the documentation in my answer...

Comment: Hi Lix - Sorry, bothering again. i've put in code (i know am not writing it correctly - but cant find the error) its not working. can u help in once again.. thnx a lot.

Comment: Have you got error reporting on? What exactly is not working? Is the share dialog being shown to the user?

Comment: Hi on clicking share - its opening a new window - http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='$sharerpath'

Comment: As you can see from the URL, the PHP variable is simply not being parsed.  It's placing the variable name and not it's value. Try something like this - `$url = 'facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$sharerpath;`

Comment: Hi Lix - Still its not - its now opening a new window - http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php/?u='.$sharerpath''

Comment: @gag - we are talking about something very simple in PHP - placing variables in strings.  I don't know how much I can help you there.  You might have to go back and read some basic tutorials.

Comment: Yaa, am still a novice in php- yes its basic - still will seek your help for once if can to suggest. thnx a lot, it means a lot to me

Comment: @gag - I see the problem.  You have to write PHP code within the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Hi Lix - i still on a wrong node, as its either breaking the page by showing server error when the entire facebook sharing code is put in between <?php ?> tags, have put up the editable version out there